# Upload Images limitation on live laravel server

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to upload almost 30 images to my production application, but it is showing/uploading only 10 images. It seems my production server has some limits to upload the images. What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is due to time-out problem since you uploaded 30 images in a batch.

You may use the following in your php (or amend your php.ini):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '40M'); 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 80000); 
ini_set('post_max_size', '40M'); 
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');
```